# Problem on norm of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Actually, we know that the matrix group $M (n,\Bbb R)$ can be viewed as a topological space with respect to a point of the respective co-ordinates in $\Bbb R^{n^2}$ and the norm function can be defined as $||A||$ corresponding to the norm of the co-ordinate of the matrix $A$ .And, under this norm, obviously $||A||=||A^t|| , A^t$ is transpose of $A$ .

Now, under the norm, $||A||=\sup_{\Vert x\Vert=1}\Vert Ax\Vert$, for any matrix $A$ in  $M (n,\Bbb R)$, how to prove $||A||=||A^t||$ ?

[Obviously, the above norm is well-defined as $S^{n-1}$ is compact in $\Bbb R^n$ and $x→\Vert Ax\Vert$ is continuous.]

Comment: Can please someone edit the text using Latex or MathJax as I am completely unable of doing it .

Comment: The definition of the operator norm depends on the norm you pick for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Are you using the Euclidean norm?

Comment: To cmk, no Sir, it is not the Euclidean norm, rather it is the norm defined by the continuous function stated above .

Comment: I meant, what is the norm for $\|x\|?$ If you take the operator norm induced by, say, the $\ell_1$ norm, then this is obviously not true. This question has already been marked as a duplicate, but still.

Comment: @cmk, sorry Sir, for my misunderstanding, yes , I do follow Euclidean norm for the operator, but Sir can you please answer about why the result doesn't hold for the  L1 norm ???

Comment: If $\|A\|_p$ is the operator norm induced by the $p$ norm, then $\|A\|_1=\|A^T\|_\infty,$ and this does not have to be equal to $\|A^T\|_1$ (recall that the $1$ norm here is the max absolute column sum, so it's not hard to find a counterexample).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95520/discussion-between-rabi-kumar-chakraborty-and-cmk).